# How do I save the status of checkbox with "checked" attribute as default on localstorage?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, local-storage

I have set a script that makes a nav bar's position to become fixed at the top of the page after scrolling a certain amount, but some people don't like it. So I'm trying to give them the option to choose if they want it or not.

*I already have the script that makes the nav bar fixed when scrolling and if a checkbox is checked,* **but I still don't have the script that will save the checkbox status if it is changed**.

[Here is the Fiddle of what I'm basically trying to do.](https://jsfiddle.net/nwk1g6vp/25/)

I have tried to find an answer for this, but all of the answers to save checkbox status to localstorage are without the checked attribute as default and **when I add the attribute, the script no longer works**.

I'm afraid I'm still quite new to scripting and a self taught at that, so i haven't been able to figure out how to solve this. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Have you tried to write code for working with localstorage by yourself? If so - please attach example of not working code.

Comment: Not by myself. As I said in the last paragraph, I'm quite new to scripting. I did add one of the scripts I found and tried to the fiddle, though. It doesn't work at first, but if you remove the "checked" attribute in html, it suddenly works.